# how to remove double quotes from a dictionary keys?

Tags: python

I have:

```
{'"Phone numbers"': ['0010', '55200', 'Full Names'], '"Phone numbers"': ['0015','163810', 'Full Names']
```

how to remove double quotes from a dictionary keys?

Comment: consider using `dictionary[re.sub('"','',old_key)] = dictionary.pop(old_key)`

Comment: that isn't even a valid dictionary as there are repeated keys

Comment: Do all of the keys in your dictionary begin and end with double-quotes? Could any keys have an odd number of double-quotes - e.g., '"a"b"'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.replace` in a dict-comprehension for example

```
x = {'"Phone numbers"': ['0010', '55200', 'Full Names'], '"Phone numbers"': ['0015','163810', 'Full Names']
x = {k.replace('"', ''): values for k,values in x.items()}
```